# Почему, если внутри CROSS APPLY есть агрегат, то он работает, как OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Для примера, есть простая таблица с данными:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
id int,
num int 
) 
GO
INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES  
    (1,1000)
   ,(2,1000)
   ,(3,2000)
   ,(4,2000)
   ,(5,3000)
   ,(6,3000)
```

Тут CROSS APPLY работает верно:

```
select *
from tbl t1
CROSS APPLY (select top 1 id from tbl t2 where t1.num = -1 order by id asc) apply_min
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я пытаюсь то же самое сделать через агрегатную функцию, то CROSS APLLY работает, как OUTER.
Почему?

```
select *
from tbl t1
CROSS APPLY (select min(id) min from tbl t2 where t1.num = -1) apply_min
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нашёл ответ на [англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691929/cross-apply-with-aggregates)

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае подзапрос не возвращает строк, а во втором - возвращает (NULL).

Comment: в том то и дело, что первый и второй случай - запросы идентичные, вопрос - почему разный результат

Comment: Я же вам сказал, что не идентичные. В первом случае нет ни одной строки, а во втором одна строка. Поэтому здесь работает CROSS APPLY, как он и должен работать. У вас MIN возвращает NULL в строке.